# How to find webElement a href that has image as link in java?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver, testng

```
<a href="/astana/" title="Главная страница" rel="index">
        <img src="/img/lkz.png" width="107" height="38" alt="naimi.kz logo">
</a>
```

I have this html code for website i m testing.I m writing java test using testNG,

```
WebElement logo = firefox.findElement(By.linkText("<img src="/img/lkz.png" width="107" height="38" alt="naimi.kz logo">")) ;
```

The question is: should I locate by "/astana/" in ahref or locate by `<img src>`?

Locating by img src does not work, because it has lots of double quotes inside it( i escaped them with backslash, but still it gives me error as NotFoundElement exception)

so I m in doubt as to what to use to locate this image logo in java.

Comment: Do you want to find only 1 image OR all images from that page?

Comment: This question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582163/save-img-src-tag-as-string-in-java-and-find-in-webdriver cover the same site.  It could be more successful to make just one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath expression to find this image. Just use `By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/astana/\"]/img")`. This will find you any `<img>` node under the `<a>` node with `href` attribute equals to '/astana/'.

Comment: almost! except that you added bad single quotes , i deleted them and now this is the right answer, still kudos to you , the answer is  (By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/astana/\"]/img") ) ;

Comment: You are right, I forgot to delete single quotes, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector as

```
tagName[attributeName='itsValue']
```

for your case it can be written as img[src='/img/lkz.png']